# Quadratic variation of Square of a continuous martingale

Tags: stochastic-analysis

> **Problem:**
>
> Show that if $(M_t)$ is a continuous local martingale, then $M^2$ has quadratic variation
> $$\langle M^2\rangle_t=4\int_0^tM_s^2\mathrm{d}\langle M\rangle_s$$

It seems to me that $M^2$ is a semi-martingale with decomposition $M_t^2 = (M_t^2-\langle M\rangle_t)+\langle M\rangle_t$, so I have $\langle M^2\rangle_t=\langle (M^2-\langle M\rangle)\rangle_t$. But I don't know how to proceed.

Any help is appreciated!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By Ito's formula, $$M_t^2 = 2\int_0^t M_s dM_s + \int_0^t d\langle M,M \rangle_s$$ so
\begin{align*}
\langle M^2,M^2\rangle_t &= \left\langle 2\int_0^t M_s dM_s ,2\int_0^t M_s dM_s \right\rangle \\
&= 4\left\langle \int_0^t M_s dM_s ,\int_0^t M_s dM_s \right\rangle \\
&= 4\int_0^t M_s^2 d\langle M,M\rangle_s.
\end{align*}